Setting TListView to OwnerDraw aligns the icons incorrectly
See below (Rad Studio 12), a New Form with a TListView, 5 items added at design time, the only properties changed is ViewStyle set to vsIcon, and AutoArrange under IconOptions set to True.
The listview displays correctly:

However, just by setting OwnerDraw to True, the alignment of the icons now moves to the bottom:

The goal is to be able to custom draw the listview items so that I can paint a filled rectangle where the item image would be, then draw the image back on top of the filled rectangle, however the alignment of the icons is undesired behaviour.
What is causing this behaviour?

I can reproduce the issue with a plain Win32 ListView, so this is likely a bug in the underlying API. It is not a problem with the VCL.

Thanks for confirming. I've tried searching the issue to no avail so not sure where I go from here, I could attempt writing my own custom control, or if TVirtualStringTree can be used to represent an icon style thumbnail view maybe that could work. Do you have any suggestions please?

Guess AI killed off Stack Overflow lol, I remember a time when this place was thriving..
